# Avoid referencing a roll up summary field from child record

Tags: formula, roll-up-summary, documentation

In reading the documentation on [Roll-Up Summary Field](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en), I found":

> Avoid referencing a roll-up summary field from a child record. The roll-up summary fields referenced from child records can have outdated values, because their parent records have not been updated. Instead, reference roll-up summary fields from parent records. Your roll-up summary fields will always have updated values, because that rule runs after the parent value has been updated.

What does this mean? I created a formula field on child record that references the rollup summary field on parent. Whenever the value of roll up changes in parent it does gets reflected in child record. I am trying to understand what the document statement is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are talking about using roll-up summary fields referenced in validation rules from child records:

> Your roll-up summary fields will always have updated values, because
>   **that rule runs** after the parent value has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Oleksiy's answer, we could reword the paragraph as:

> Avoid referencing a parent's roll-up summary field from a child record validation rule. The parent roll-up summary fields referenced from child records can have outdated values, because their parent records have not been updated. Instead, reference parent roll-up summary fields from parent record validation rules. Your roll-up summary fields will always have updated values, because validation rules runs after the parent roll-up summary value has been updated.